# How to find cities without nearby bigger city in SpatiaLite?

Tags: spatialite, sqlite

I have a table `cities`, each with a `population INTEGER` and a `geom POINT` location (WGS84). I'm trying to **select all cities where there is not a more populous city within 50 km** using the latest SpatiaLite (4.3.0).

This has to use a spatial index because there are almost 200000 cities, so doing a full table scan for each of them would be too slow. I understand that (unlike PostGIS) SpatiaLite won't automatically use my spatial index, but I found [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148589/spatialite-spatial-index-on-geometries) that I thought should help.

This is the setup (slightly simplified):

```
sqlite> .load mod_spatialite.so
sqlite> SELECT InitSpatialMetaData();
1
sqlite> CREATE TABLE cities (
          id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
          name STRING NOT NULL,
          population INTEGER NOT NULL
        );
sqlite> SELECT AddGeometryColumn('cities', 'geom', 4326, 'POINT', 'XY', 1);
1
sqlite> INSERT INTO cities VALUES (1, 'One', 500, MakePoint(0.0, 0.0, 4326));
sqlite> INSERT INTO cities VALUES (2, 'Two', 300, MakePoint(1.0, 0.0, 4326));
```

Here's what I thought should work:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM cities AS a
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT i.ROWID
          FROM SpatialIndex AS i, cities AS b
          WHERE
            i.ROWID = b.ROWID AND
            f_table_name = 'cities' AND
            search_frame = ST_Expand(a.geom, 50000.0) AND
            b.ROWID <> a.ROWID AND
            ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom, FALSE) < 50000.0 AND
            b.population > a.population
        );
1|One|500|
2|Two|300|
```

But no matter how large I set the distance, this query always returns both cities. Maybe this is because the spatial index seems to be empty:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM SpatialIndex;
sqlite>
```

So then obviously, no matter what I put in the innermost `WHERE` clause, it's going to come back empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, is there any up to date documentation? The SpatiaLite cookbook seems to be outdated, because it doesn't use this `SpatialIndex` virtual table.

Comment: @JGH `ST_Distance` with a third argument is supposed to return meters though. `ST_Expand` documentation doesn't say what the units are, but even if they're degrees, it would just make my query less efficient, not less correct.